# Build failed trying to follow Firebase for Flutter tutorial (Android Studio)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

New to mobile app dev, I am attempting to follow this Firebase for Flutter tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#4

Importing the firestore package per the very first line in main.dart is presumably what is causing the following result when I try to run it. Am I not following the tutorial correctly?? My code looks exactly as in the tutorial. I copied & pasted.

This is with Android Studio 3.5.3.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:248: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:269: error: cannot find symbol
                    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction)
                                       ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
                    @Nullable
                     ^
  symbol: class Nullable
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:495: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:548: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Finished with error: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

------------------------
```

Comment: Post details of your code. As this is androidx issue, the flutter version, plugin version, and how did you create the project all decide whether you have androidx support..

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. It was the cloud_firestore version that was wrong. (different from the tutorial)  My bad!